# Change color of alternate row in UITableView for iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, I want to display multi-column tableView in iPad.

So, I used a cocoa control from :[MultiColumn TableView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/multicolumntableviewforios)

it works fine for me, But I want to display the rows in alternate color.

For this, I am not able to find where I change the code for it.

Comment: alternate Row ?? which row please elaborate you question..

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can put that code.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
 
        if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
              cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        else
              cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution does not work well with tables with sections. You would want the **absolute** row of the table, which can be found with this category I implemented: https://github.com/edekhayser/UITableView-RowConvenience

Comment: The solution works perfect!!, But this is strange that, if you not write else part, it will not work after scrolling!!!, shouldn't table view take default color for else part.

Answer (score 9):

use the indexPath in the   `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the desired results.

```
    if( [indexPath row] % 2){
          cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    } 
    else{
          cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
    }
```

You will have this delegate method in the class which is implementing the `UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: Thanks for reply! There are so many files in it.so i can't able  to find the method for change the code. If you ever used this control, then please tell me the file name in which i will change the code.

Comment: You need to set this in your class which is implementing the `UITableViewDelegate`

Answer (score 6):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    .......

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }
    .......

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First you need to take modulas of each row.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    .......

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }
    ....


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Anybody trying to do this in swift then here is my code. Tiny and superb.

This trick works with even static cells where I don't use the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Sorry for little answer. Hope you know about datasource an delegates.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    
    if (indexPath.row % 2) != 0{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor .blackColor()
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor .lightGrayColor()

    }

 }
```

It will give you the result like...

[image: Color each alternate cell in ios using Swift]

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
    if(indexPath.row%2==0)
        cell.contentView. backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    else
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

        


return cell;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! There are so many files in it.so i can't able  to find the method for change the code. If you ever used this control, then please tell me the file name in which i will change the code.

Answer (score 1):

Search for cellForRowAtIndexPath in your code. that method is responsible for creating cell in your tableview.
for more info : [UITableViewCell with alternate background color in customized cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169281/uitableviewcell-with-alternate-background-color-in-customized-cells)

Answer (score 1):

In your cellForRow method you should check if indexPath.row is divisible by 2 assign first color, else assign second color and return the resulting cell

Answer (score 1):

```
func colorForIndex(index: Int) -> UIColor 
{
    let itemCount = stnRepos.count - 1
    let color = (CGFloat(index) / CGFloat(itemCount)) * 0.6
    return UIColor(red: 0.80, green: color, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{        
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = colorForIndex(indexPath.row)
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift 3** + and with reduced opacity:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.05)
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In such a simple example I would go for ternary operator. I just hate to see the cell.backgroundColor duplicated.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

.
.
.
    cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.05) : .white
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a loop which will increment the index path.row by 2 and then in the body of that loop you can assign the color.,

Answer (score 0):

**This is working code for Swift 4.x & Above**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor =  UIColor.lightGray
    }
}
```