# TableView every other cell one color

Tags: swift, colors, tableview

Is there a way to color every other cell one color on a `tableView`? I tried looking into the properties for my `tableView` but were not able to find anything.

I want it like this:

```
tableview
 cell - white
 cell - gray
 cell - white
 cell - gray
```

etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color alternate UITableViewCell in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505330/color-alternate-uitableviewcell-in-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will be to do this programmatically in your `cellForRowAt` function:

```
if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**One line** code, if you want

```
 cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? .white : .gray
```